# How to restrict direct access via URL in react-router-dom

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have many routes in the project and I have a number of defined permissions.And according to those permissions, the user can do things .How to I prevent user from accessing the page  directly by entering the URL ..Part of my code:

```
 return (
            this.state.auth ?
                <div className="wrapper" >
                    <div id='content' className={this.state.isSidebarActive ? "content" : "content-active"}>

                        <Switch>
                            <Route exact path='/main' >
                                <Redirect to='/main/customers/real' />
                            </Route>
                      
                            <Route path="/main/messages"><Messages isSidebarActive={this.state.isSidebarActive} /></Route>                        
                            <Route path="/main/algorithms"><Algorithm isSidebarActive={this.state.isSidebarActive} /></Route>
                            <Route path="/main/electronicPayment"><ElectronicPayment isSidebarActive={this.state.isSidebarActive} /></Route>
                         
                        </Switch>
                    </div>
                </div>
                : ''
        );
```

I want to limit URL based on these:

```
 var PermissionList=this.state.PermissionList 
                    //var PermissionList=["IdentityManagementTab"] 
                    if (Array.isArray(PermissionList)) {
                     var exists = (item, arr) => arr.some(e => e === item);
                     var IdentityManagementTab = exists("IdentityManagementTab", PermissionList);
                   
                     var TseTradeManagementTab = exists("TseTradeManagementTab", PermissionList);
                     var FundManagementTab = exists("FundManagementTab", PermissionList);
                     var BankManagementTab = exists("BankManagementTab", PermissionList);
                     var MsgManagementTab = exists("MsgManagementTab", PermissionList);
                     var AlgorithmManagementTab = exists("AlgorithmManagementTab", PermissionList);
                     var SocialNetworkManagementTab = exists("SocialNetworkManagementTab", PermissionList);
                     var SejamManagementTab = exists("SejamManagementTab", PermissionList);
                    }
```

I want, for example, if the message does not exist, it can not enter that page via URL

I found this solution:

```
  <Route  path="/main/messages" render={() => (
  MsgManagementTab ? (
    <Messages isSidebarActive={this.state.isSidebarActive} />
  ) : (
    <NoAccess  isSidebarActive={this.state.isSidebarActive} />
  )
)}/>
```

....

But for many routes, is that right?
Is there no other solution?

Comment: Are you asking about authorization validation to prevent access to given routes, or simply prevent direct navigation to a route because these are two very different questions?

Comment: prevent direct navigation to a route

Comment: You could send a "slug" payload in route state transitions and check for it on the receiving route's component. If the slug exists, render the component, if not, redirect them back to a main page. A user navigating directly to these URLs won't have the payload.

Comment: I do not know how to do this. Give a small example

Comment: I'm describing something like [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/how-to-restrict-direct-access-via-url-in-react-router-dom-eh7z1). Let me know if that is in the direction of what you're looking for.

Comment: thank you for devoting your time to answering my questions

Comment: I updated my questions

Comment: For example, how should I use slug for <Messages /> with condition MsgManagementTab ?

Comment: What you describe there with an access list sounds more like an "auth check" than blocking external navigation. Check the [Auth Workflow](https://reactrouter.com/web/example/auth-workflow) in the react-router-dom docs. It should give you a good idea of the direction you need to head.